# Security of WebSocket in light of no same origin connection policy

Tags: javascript, html, security, websocket

I am worried about the security implications of the fact that WebSockets can open connections to servers other than the one from which the script was loaded.  Is there at least a plugin I can install that would tell me if a WebSocket is opening a connection to a non-originating server?  I can imagine falling victim to a Cross Site Scripting attack, which then opens up a WebSocket to some malicious server.

Is this really a problem?  If so, why is it allowed?

Comment: What kind of security problem are you worried about?  A script can already use JSONP to connect to a cooperating (e.g. supports JSONP), non-originating server.  Same things for WebSockets.  Plus, any program or server (outside of a browser) can connect to a WebSocket too.  If you choose to support WebSockets on your server, then you have to know that anyone can connect to it and act accordingly.

Comment: If you are "a victim of xss", then stop worrying and _enjoy the ride_, coz "opening websocket to another site" is among the last things you should worry about ;)

Comment: I see that as of the 20140604 WebSocket draft this warning text has been added: "Following HTTP procedures here could introduce serious security problems in a Web browser context. For example, consider a host with a WebSocket server at one path and an open HTTP redirector at another. Suddenly, any script that can be given a particular WebSocket URL can be tricked into communicating to (and potentially sharing secrets with) any host on the Internet, even if the script checks that the URL has the right hostname." At least they are aware of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check whether a cross origin WebSocket is about to be opened then you can use this code:

```
(function(w) {
    var org_websocket = w.WebSocket,
        reg_host = location.host.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
        pattern = new RegExp("^(ws|wss)://"+reg_host+"(/.*)?$");

    w.WebSocket = function(url) {
        if (!pattern.test(url)) {
            alert("cross site websocket");
        }
        return new org_websocket(url);
    };
})(window);
```

If you ensure that it runs before any other script then you'll be in control. This is still not 100% secure since the original WebSocket class can be retrieved by other means ( iframes? ). And there are probably other security holes in JavaScript that I'm not aware of. On the other hand it is always possible to hack a client, you should not rely on that.

Now as for security. It is an issue and it can be a serious one. But on the other hand it cannot be prevented with simple HTTP either (JSONP). That's why cross site requests policy is getting weaker (it's a big restriction for normal developers while not being secure at all).

For example we already have [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). So it is up to developers to ensure that their WebServers are secure (i.e. proper escaping of whatever a user passes to the server).